# Can I make an alias of variable in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to check existence of a variable in bash like following.

```
if [ -z "$VARIABLE" ]; then
  echo "VARIABLE does not exist"
else
  echo "VARIABLE exist"
fi
```

It works fine. But in the next step, I would like to generate a variable name and check whether the variable with the variable name exists or not like following.

```
function generate_var_name() { echo "aaa" }

VARIABLE_NAME=$(generate_var_name)
if [ -z ${$VARIABLE_NAME:-""} ]; then  # This give error message below.
  echo "VARIABLE does not exist"
else
  echo "VARIABLE exist"
fi
```

However it did not work. Its error messages was

```
${"$INCLUD_GUARD_NAME":-""}: bad substitution
```

Again, what I would like to do is 
  (1) generate a variable name, nameA, and store it to another variable, VarB.
  (2) using the variable varB, check whether variable with nameA exists or not.

Someone who has solution or suggestion, please tell me it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `-z` doesn't test if a variable exists; it tests if its expansion is the empty string. Use `[ -v VARIABLE ]` to test if the variable is set at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want an indirect expansion of a variable. Also, it appears that the conditions are reversed in your conditional.

```
export aaa=foobar
VARIABLE_NAME=aaa

if [ -n "${!VARIABLE_NAME}" ]; then
  echo "VARIABLE exist"
else
  echo "VARIABLE does not exist"
fi
```

**Update**: As @chepner correctly pointed out, the test above does not actually check for whether a variable is defined, but rather whether the variable evaluates to an empty string. This check works only if the goal is to consider an undefined variable and a variable defined to equal to the empty string equivalent. Please see @chepner's answer for a correct existence check of a variable.

Comment: Thank you, merlin2011. Expansion as variable name you mention aobve was what I want. Thank you again.

Comment: Plus1. Also, just for the record, if you want to make an array access, you need to do something like this: `var='aaa[3]'; value="${!var}"` and not `var='aaa'; value="${!var[3]}"`...

Comment: This tests if a variable has  a non-empty value, not if it is set.

Comment: @chepner, I've updated to answer to include the correction and a pointer to your answer. Please feel free to edit if you think there's a more clear way to express the correction, since I didn't see the use in duplicating your answer and cannot delete mine since it is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` already has a test for the existence of a variable:

```
foo=3   # non-empty value
bar=    # empty value
# baz is not set
for v in foo bar baz; do
    if [[ -v $v ]]; then
        echo "$v is set; its value is ${!v}"
    else
        echo "$v is not set"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you, chepner for giving me advance technique. If you don't mind could you give me a way to learn options in [[ ]]? I searched [[ ]] but i could get some information mainly for matching but I could not get enough information you provided. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you again, chepner. I could get it.